# Finding Bigrams in a list of worrds

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, corpus

How would I go about finding a bigram in a list? For example, if I wanted to find the

```
bigram = list(nltk.bigrams("New York"))
```

In a list of words,

```
words = nltk.corpus.brown.words(fileids=["ca44"])
```

I have tried doing,

```
for t in bigram:
        if t in words:
             *do something*
```

As well as,

```
if bigram in words:
   *do something*
```

Answer (score 2):

`.bigrams()` will return a generator of tuples. You should convert the tuples to strings first. For example:

```
bigram_strings = [''.join(t) for t in bigram]
```

then you can do

```
for t in bigram_strings:
    if t in words:
         *do something*
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my question isn't clear enough :S, What I am after is to be able to find occurrences of where there is ('new', 'york') together . What you have suggested although good prints 'newyork'

Comment: Then you are better with @L3viathan's answer, but I think you should use `for bigram in nltk.bigrams(["New", "York"]):` then.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generator that yields bigrams for your word list:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    """Iterate over pairs of an iterable."""
    i = iter(iterable)
    j = iter(iterable)
    next(j)
    yield from zip(i, j)
```

(For example, `list(pairwise(["this", "is", "a", "test"]))` will return `[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'test')]`.)

And then zip over that and the result of `.bigrams()`:

```
for pair in pairwise(words):
    for bigram in nltk.bigrams("New York"):
        if bigram == pair:
            pass  # found
```